# VBscript writing to a textarea and submitting

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write to a text area and submit after logging into a website. I'm getting an error when trying to append the text area, are there any other ways of doing this?

The first function Main is running fine - IE opens and logins into the website properly. I'm then moved to the page called slackbot where the textarea is. I'm able to add the text to the field, but unable to submit.

The Code:

```
Const dirPath     = "C:\Users\tim.mcgee\Desktop\Offsite Drive"
Const alertedPath = "prevRun.txt"
      alertOn     = 3 * 2 ^ 29 '1.5GB
      resetOn     = alertOn * .95 'Approx 77MB
Const emailTo     = "temcgee7@gmail.com"
Const emailFrom   = "temcgee7@gmail.com"
Const emailSbjct  = "Offsite Drive Full"
Const emailMsg    = "The offsite drive has reached maximum capacity."
Const SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"
Const SMTPPort    = 465
      emailUsr    = emailFrom 
Const emailPsswd  = "Electricboat1"
Const emailSSL    = False


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(alertedPath) Then
  alerted =  CBool(Trim(fso.OpenTextFile(alertedPath).ReadLine))
Else
  alerted = False
End If
dirSize = fso.GetFolder(dirPath).Size

If alerted Then 'Email previously sent
  alerted = dirSize > resetOn
ElseIf dirSize >= alertOn Then
  Call Main
  alerted = True
End If

fso.OpenTextFile(alertedPath, 2, True).WriteLine CInt(alerted)
WScript.Quit 0

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://epic.slack.com/messages/@slackbot/"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("email").value = "tim.mcgee@epicgames.com"
        .getElementByID("password").value = "Electricboat1"
        .getElementByID("signin_btn").click()
    End With

    WScript.Sleep 5000

    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("message-input").appendChild(IE.Document.createtextnode("@channel: Offsite drive is reaching maximum capacity. Please delete old builds."))
        .getElementByID("message-input").submit()
    End With

End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 2000
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```